# Unable to see some Russian id3 tags in ncmpc

Tags: terminal, unicode, id3

I'm running **urxvt** with the current env:

```
$ env | grep LC
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

The problem is either with ncurses or ncmpc and I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on what the problem might be. This could also be an issue with the **ID3** tags and any advice on working  with broken or misconfigured encoding settings in meta tags in mp3 files is also welcome. I have been ignoring this matter for years and it has finally gotten to me. The bizarre thing is that some filenames or tags work, while others do not.

What I have tried the following:

- setting LC_ALL to these values (whatever is before the space)

  - ru_RU.KOI8-R KOI8-R
  - ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8
  - ru_RU ISO-8859-5
- rebuilding the MPD database with

  - id3v1_encoding                  "ISO-8859-1" 
    *or*
  - id3v1_encoding                  "UTF-8"

I can demonstrate the problem with two screen shots, as it's the easiest way to do so:

Expected output (mpc works well):

[image: expected output]

Broken encoding (ncmpc):

[image: broken encoding]

Ncmpcpp: same problem

[image: ncmpcpp: same problem]

Answer (score 0):

From the second screenshot, it looks like `ncmpcpp` outputs valid UTF-8, but *your terminal* does not expect it.

Find out the PID of your terminal emulator, then run

```
cat /proc/<PID>/environ | tr \\0 \\n | egrep "LANG|LC"
```

If it shows something different than your current locale, then you're likely setting $LANG/$LC_ALL in the wrong place. For example, `.bashrc` won't work because it is not applied to the X11 session, only to programs *inside* a terminal – `.profile` or `.xprofile` would be better.

In fact, setting $LC_ALL permanently is not recommended – just `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` should be enough. (Try to avoid ISO-8859 or KOI8-R settings.)

Comment: The application in the screen-shot is ncmpc, not ncmpcpp. $ cat /proc/9411/environ (...): LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8. I start X with startx, so the locale variables in subsequent terminals are set to the same values as they are when X launces. If the terminal had not expected UTF-8, then mpc (mpc-whatson) would certainly not show the correct characters, but it does. I included the mpc screen-shot only to show that. The weird part is that some tags work, while others do not. That's also part of the question, and if locale vars were bad, none of them would work.